# Not getting the dynamic dependent list value while editing the form

Tags: laravel, dropdown

> I am using dynamic dependent dropdown list.Where subcategory is dependent on category.In my edit view I want to get my previous selected dropdown value in my form.But I only get the selected category..value. But not the subcategory value...I dont know how to fix it

```
<div class="form-row col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="margin-left: 5px">
        <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Category</label>
        <select class="chosen-select form-control"   name="category">
            <option value="">Select category</option>
            @foreach ($categories as  $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{$product->category_id==$category->id?'selected':''}}>{{$category->category_name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        {{$errors->first('category')}}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6" style="margin-left: 5px" >
        <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Sub Category</label>
        <select class=" chosen form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory"></select>
        {{$errors->first('subcategory')}}
    </div>
</div>
```

> here is my ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="category"]').on('change', function() {
            var stateID = $(this).val();
            console.log(stateID)
            if(stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+stateID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="subcategory"]').append('<option value="' + key + '">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> controller

```
 public function myformAjax($id)

{

    $subcategories = DB::table("subcategories")

                ->where("category_id",$id)

                ->pluck("subcategory_name","id");

    return json_encode($subcategories);

}
public function edit($id)
{
     $categories = Category::latest()->get();
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    return view('product.edit',compact('categories','product'));
}
```

> route

```
    Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::resource('group', 'GroupController');
    Route::resource('company', 'CompanyController');
    Route::resource('slider', 'SliderController');
    Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
    Route::resource('subcategory', 'SubcategoryController');
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');

});


Route::get('myform/ajax/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax','uses'=>'HomeController@myformAjax'));
```

Comment: post also the controller

Comment: and the route please (please after a edit comment the question with my name "@AlbertoSinigaglia", otherwise i won't be alert of the changes)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DB::table...` will return a object, but you need to have an array, so you can use or `all()` or `toArray()` after the `pluck(...)` call like this:

```
$subcategories = DB::table("subcategories")->where("category_id",$id)->pluck("subcategory_name","id")->all();
```